# Propagating visitor IP through nginx

Tags: ip, nginx, node.js

I have a node.js site fronted by nginx. So that when request gets to the site the IP in the request is 127.0.0.1
Is there anyway to modify the request while it is under nginx control so that node.js can see the true IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking to do is run a reverse proxy. The settings you can change are part of the `X-Forward` family.
What you want to do is try configuring the following in your nginx configuration:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

If that does not work (you cannot utilize those headers) you can also try the realip module found here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

Comment: In my case the header delivered to node.js looked like
req[ 'x-real-ip' ]
Notice the lower case although I did exactly like you've suggested.
But all is good what ends good, so thank you very much!